# not able to write to file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

```
class PostCallbacks < XML::SAX::Document
  test = "";
  out = File.open("output.txt","w");
  def start_element(element = "", attributes = [])
      @out << element
  end
end
```

gives error: `undefined method`<<' for nil:NilClass`

why can I not write to file this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class PostCallbacks < XML::SAX::Document
  test = "";
  def initialize
    @out = File.open("output.txt","w");
  end
  def start_element(element = "", attributes = [])
    @out << element
  end
end
```

The error you're getting tells you that `@out` isn't initialized properly. The safest way to do what you're attempting to do is to initialize the *instance* variable `@out` in the constructor, which is to say, the `initialize` method.

Even better, of course, would be to pass the name of the output file to the constructor, rather than hard-coding it.